# SwiftUI ListView

Tags: ios, swiftui

I try to build interface with tableview with lists in SwiftUI, but cannot figure out how to make tableview with empty spaces like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a form with sections, like

```
struct DemoView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section {
                NavigationLink("Upgrade to Premium", destination: Text("Some"))
            }
            Section {
                Button("Rate this app") {}
                Button("Share this app") {}
                Button("Feedback") {}
            }
            Section {
                Button("My other apps") {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*Note: assuming it has `NavigationView` somewhere in parent to make `NavigationLink` working.*